# Create a workflow management system

Tags: workflow, workflow-engine

I am creating a scientific workflow system for my final year project. I want to deploy it on cloud rather on the grid. How should I go about it? I don't have any idea about the  coding required and how to use a WF engine. I am thinking about using Pegasus(as it is Java based) and Dagman for DAX.

Please guide me from scratch as I am completely lost.
Thanks.